# optimization question help

Tags: calculus, integration

Please help on this question i do not know how to do it

sand flows from a hole in the bottom of a tank at a rate of $r(t)=120 - 6t$ kg/hour where t is measure in hours nad $0 \leq t \leq 20$. How many kg flows out of the tank in the first 5 hours?

Answer (score 1):

The rate of outflow is the rate at which the quantity of sand lost from the tank is increasing. That is, if $m(t)$ is the total mass of sand lost from the tank at time $t$,

$$\frac{dm}{dt}=r(t)=120-6t\;.$$

That says that at time $t=0$ the lost mass is increasing at a rate of $120$ kg/hr; $5$ hours later it’s increasing at rate of only $90$ kg/hr. Now just integrate:

$$m=\int dm=\int(120-6t)dt\;.$$

Of course something is missing there: that’s an indefinite integral, and the problem clearly demands a definite integral: the result must be a number. The integral is in terms of time ($dt$), and the limits are exactly what you’d expect: we want the total mass lost from $t=0$ to $t=5$. The integral is therefore

$$\int_0^5(120-6t)dt\;.$$